# SuiteCRM v7.10.29 Custom API v4.1

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

I am creating a custom API for SuiteCRM. When I attempt to run the new API from {CRM Home}/custom/service/v4_1_custom I receive an 'HTTP ERROR 500'. There are not errors in the error_log file or the SuiteCRM.log file.

I have followed the method in the following two url's
https://fayebsg.com/2013/05/extending-the-sugarcrm-api-updating-dropdowns/
https://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_10.0/Integration/Web_Services/Legacy_API/Extending_Web_Services/

```
registry.php

<?php

require_once('service/v4_1/registry.php');
class registry_v4_1_custom extends registry_v4_1
{
    protected function registerFunction()
    {

        parent::registerFunction();
        $this->serviceClass->registerFunction('test', array(), array());

    }
}
```

```
SugarWebServicesImplv4_1_custom.php

<?php


if(!defined('sugarEntry'))define('sugarEntry', true);

require_once('service/v4_1/SugarWebServiceImplv4_1.php');

class SugarWebServiceImplv4_1_custom extends SugarWebServiceImplv4_1
{
    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function test()
    {

        LoggerManager::getLogger()->warn('SugerWebServiceImplv4_1_custom test()');

        return ("Test Worked");
    }   // test
}   // SugarWebServiceImplv4_1_custom
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to this issue.

In the file {SuiteCRM}/include/entryPoint.php there are many files that are included thru require_once. In this list of require_once files, there were 4 files that were set as require not require_once. These were classes and therefore could not be included a second time. I changed these to require_once and the HTTP Error 500 went away and the custom APIs started working.